# SFML SIGSEGV fault when trying to create a window

Tags: c++, sfml, segmentation-fault

I updated my sfml from 1.6 to 2.1 yesterday, and after porting my old project I found out that this code (even after simplifing whole project to just int main() with only those two instructions) is making SIGSEGV faults:

```
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow* window;

    //this V SIGSEGVs
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "app", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    delete window;
}
```

I use Code::Blocks\MinGw.

Any sugestions what should I do to repair this?

Edit:
It is window creation instruction that crashes.
I'm getting following warning when compiling code from the whole project:

```
warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
||Info: resolving vtable for sf::Sprite by linking to __imp___ZTVN2sf6SpriteE |
||Info: resolving sf::RenderStates::Default      by linking to __imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE |
||Info: resolving vtable for sf::Transformable by linking to __imp___ZTVN2sf13TransformableE
```

Comment: Is it the actual construction of the window that crashes, or when you try to use it afterwards? Can you please show a more complete example (see [here for some help](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Also, are you linking with the correct libraries (i.e. the version 2 library and not the old 1.6 library)? How about any compiler warnings, do you get any of those?

Comment: Posted an edit. I'm linking with libraries provided in 2.1 sfml pack that I downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried using a precompiled package from [sfml-dev.org](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php)?

Comment: Yes, GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 32 bits package, DW2 didn't worked